# get notification at specific time for once

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

Here i need to get the notification at a specific date. This is what I have done so far.

here is my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();     
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.MAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 24);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 19);


    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);            
    PendingIntent pintent =
                        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
  }
}
```

Here is my receiver.

```
  public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {       
     notificationStatus(context);
  }


/**
 * To show notification for the alarm on time that is set as reminder
 * @param context
 */

private void notificationStatus(Context context) {
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    final int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    final CharSequence tickerText = context.getString(R.string.event);
    final long when = System.currentTimeMillis();


    final Notification notification = new Notification(
            icon, "Happy Birthday", when);
    final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(
            context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, tickerText,
            "Happy Birthday", contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}

}
```

Everything works fine. I get the notification exactly when needed but the notification also appears every time when I open the application. What's the problem in my code.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Your code should display the `Notification` immediately if the time is in the past. Depending on what the current time is compared with your hard-coded values, you would get the `Notification` immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Its becuase you have place your `notification` generation code in the onCreate() method of the application so it will call every time when you open the `activity`. so make one method for creating the `notification` and call it when you want to generate `notification`.

Comment: The `Notification` is *not* created in `onCreate()` of an `Application`, or even in `onCreate()` of an `Activity`.